# Pycharm. Как мне подключить докер?

Tags: python, django, pycharm, channels

Мне нужно выполнить команду

```
$ docker run -p 6379:6379 -d redis:5
```

на pycharm на windows. Как это сделать через pycharm?
Я запускаю Django сервер (с использованием channels) и мне нужно докер развернуть. Может кто то подробно объяснить как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

В окне пичарма внизу слева находите слово `Terminal`. кликаете по нему и вам откроется терминал. В него и вводите вашу строчку.

Comment: (venv) C:\Users\PycharmProjects\djangoProject>docker
"docker" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.

Comment: У меня windows стоит а не убунта и через терминал не прокатило

Comment: Ну так установите сначала докер. Инструкции по установке в интернете есть.